# Assign new tab names without knowing previous tab names

Tags: vba, excel, tabs

At the beginning of my Excel macro, I'm prompting the user for two tab names (old_tab and new_tab) and storing those as strings. I want to be able to take those two strings and assign them as the tab names to the first two tabs in my workbook.

However, I need to do this without knowing the current tab names. Is it possible to assign tab names based on the order of the worksheets in the workbook?

For example, the old_tab will always be assigned to the first worksheet in my workbook, and the new_tab will always be the second.

If not, is it possible to get the current tab names and store them in order to rename them to the user values?

Comment: yes, you can get the names of the first and second worksheet in your workbook. However, use the VBE Project browser to see the names of the first two worksheet objects in your workbook (bear in mind that the sheet name given on the tab may be different the sheet object name in the VBE). You can then name this what you wish via the properties window and then refer directly to this sheet in code. If you post the code you have tried to make this work with, we can help you more precisely.

Comment: `worksheets(1) = "old"` and `worksheets(2) = "new"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Sheets(1).Name = old_tab
Sheets(2).Name = new_tab
```

Comment: I knew it had to be simple, but I couldn't find anything online - thank you!